# Student grade calculation Error using React js

Tags: reactjs

Failed to compile React js Error. i am creating simple project react js i am a beginner of react. i need to calculate student grade. what i tried so far written below.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

const num1 = 30;
const num2 = 30;

const tot = num1 + num2;
const grade;

if(tot > 50)
{
  grade = "Pass";
}
else
{
 grade = "fail";
}


ReactDOM.render(tot,document.getElementById('root'));
ReactDOM.render(grade,document.getElementById('root'));
```

**Error Displayed**

```
./src/index.js
  Line 12:1:  Parsing error: Unexpected token

  10 | const tot = num1 + num2;
  11 | const grad
> 12 | if(tot > 50)
     | ^
  13 | {
  14 |   grad = "Pass";
  15 | }
```

Comment: Can you show your error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass React function and return JSX from it, to get render in DOM.

```js
const Result = () => {
    const num1 = 30;
    const num2 = 30;
  const tot = num1 + num2;
  let grade = 0;
  
  if(tot > 50)
  {
    grade = "Pass";
  }
  else
  {
    grade = "fail";
  }
  
  return (
      <div>
        <h1>{grade}</h1>
        <h2>{tot}</h2>
      </div>
    );
}


ReactDOM.render(<Result />,document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>


<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: sir grade diplayed successfully.but total diplayed error

Comment: ya. how to get the grade by next line. tot and grade printed at the same line. i need to diplay grade by next line

Answer (score 0):

You should focus on reading more about React.

To solve your issue:
https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html.
You are trying to render a number, when you should render an element, any element.
See the example in the following link:
https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-mccarthy-8j38e?file=/src/index.js